Why is my Flask app not running at all on any port and any IP?
I have just deployed Flask on my free tier AWS EC2 instance. My main.py basic app runs just fine in the terminal, in the virtual environment that I created.
main.py
 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route("/")
 def testprint():
     print('''
       text test
     ''')

 testprint()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')

However, I cannot access it via port 5000, neither by using localhost nor my external IP address in the browser.
curl 127.0.0.1:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

My Security Groups inbound rules look like this:
EC2 Inbound Rules
Python and Flask versions:
flask --version
Python 3.9.16
Flask 3.0.3
Werkzeug 3.0.3

Also running nginx version: nginx/1.24.0. There is no ufw on the instance.
Tried opening up port 5000 on the inbound rules.

based on the information provided these are the list of things that i'd make sure of,

✅ inbound rule to allow port 5000
⚠️ there's no return statement on the function replace with return
try to hit the api on /, ie, 127.0.0.1:5000/ on your server localhost.
and if that works, find the public ip of the instance to hit from internet
more importantly afterall, make sure the application is running

btw, how & where have you configured nginx? anyways, you still would be able to hit directly if exposed, make sure nginx doesn't interfere with the port 5000, (ps: it doesn't by default)
happy to help further :)

Thank you for this!
I've added the return statement as suggested.
I have run both flask --app and python3 commands. When running the app with python3 is seems to be running for all IPs but with flask --app it only seems to be running on 127.0.0.1
With python3 main.py

Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Running on http://172.31.24.93:5000

With flask --app main.py run
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Port 5000 seems to be free, checked with lsof. I've deployed Nginx with the defaults. No changes made.

It is working now. It was the return statement missing in the function. Thank you so much again for this!
